# Convert the blob content of my word document into String in apex controller

Tags: string, salesforce, blob, converters, apex-code

On SalesForce ,

I've got a word document as an attachment of a custom object, i can get it as blob by selecting the body of the attachment with a SOQL query :

Attachment att = [ SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE PARENTID = '********' and ContentType='application/msword']   ;
Blob b = att.body ;

I tried to use the b.toString() function to have the content, but it didn't work.So is there any other way to convert the blob into a string that represent the text written in my word document.

```
                                       thanks
```

Answer (score 2):

***Document bodies are saved as Blobs and are base64Encoded. Please use the EncodingUtil class and bas64Encode/base64Decode methods to achieve the desired results.***

Documentation: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm

**What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?**
*If you are trying to display the doc. content and let the user edit/save it. This is not possible unless ActiveX controls are used which is another different level.*

**Please post the code if any coding help is required!**

Answer (score 1):

The b.toString() method should return a string of the blob. But keep in mind that it isn't translating the proprietary format of the word document into plain text. It's still going to be a string with some ugliness because it represents the word document format and not the text you would see when viewing from word.